# SmartGit - how do I force a cherry-pick onto the HEAD of the target branch when there are conflicts?

Tags: git, logging, diff, smartgit

I have to change my question, because it turns out that what I thought I was seeing in the filesystem is NOT what was actually the case (I have too many similarly named folders at this point)...

I'm new to Git and SmartGit, but I'm trying to separate out a large-ish repo of legacy code into smaller ones and also add in some missing commits (previous revision control was with VSS with each commit in a separate folder, don't get me started about that...)

So, basically, I have a NB repo and a webapp repo and a missing-webapp-commit folder.  I'm tracking the NB repo as a remote branch in the webapp repo.  The code that is being extracted from the NB repo into the webapp repo is all contained wiithin one folder.  Here are the steps I've taken so far:

- I've "cherry-picked" all of the commits from before the missing one, from the NB repo into the master branch of the webapp repo.
- I've switched to the NB repo master branch, deleted the "webapp" folder from the filesystem, and copied the missing-webapp-commit folder in its place (the folder has the same name).
- I've staged and committed all of the changes to the NB repo and given it the message, "webapp backup".
- I've switched back to the webapp repo master branch and now I'm in the log, looking at both branches.
- I attempt to cherry-pick the "webapp backup" commit from the NB repo branch into the master branch (of the webapp repo), which is now current.  I get conflict errors.
- I go back to the main SmartGit screen and resolve all of the conflicts with "theirs", stage, and commit.
- I now see the "webapp backup" commit on both branches.

Now comes the revised question:  Why are there differences between the "webapp backup" commit on the NB repo branch, and the one on the master branch of the webapp repo?  The differences are inside the webapp folder, not just the expected differences due to other code that happens to be in the NB repo.

How can I get my webapp repo "webapp backup" commit to match the one in the NB repo branch?

Thanks,

Rebeccah

Comment: Could the changes showing up in SmartGit's Log be related to CRLF?

Comment: No, and I actually need to change my question.  I don't know what I was comparing in my filesystem, but the "webapp backup" commit in the two branches *is* different.  So really, the question is *why* is it different, and why doesn't cherry-picking a commit from one branch into another result in the head of the target branch having the same content as the cherry-picked commit?  And how can I force it to be?

Comment: OK, I think I see the problem.  I've been trying to insert into previous history, changes that weren't preserved in the commit that immediately followed.  There's nothing in the existing commit history to undo those changes, since the diffs in the commit history are based on the commit before the one I've been trying to insert.  It's just a totally wrong idea of how to use this feature.  I would have to either re-commit from scratch (from a fresh checkout of the NB repo branch) each of of the subsequent commits, or just give up on the idea of tracking this particular revision of the code.